# Use regex to extract integer from url in a string with php

Tags: php, regex

I have a url such as the example below

```
http://www.website.com/page.php?pid=263547322425&foo=too
```

How can i use regex to get the value of pid. Thats to say the value from the end of pid= until the &?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/pid=(\d+)/', $url, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1]; // pid value
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) provides a neat way to do that:

```
$str = 'http://www.website.com/page.php?pid=263547322425&foo=too';
parse_str($str);
echo $pid;
```

Answer (score 1):

in Perl

```
if($line =~ /.+?pid=([0-9]+)\&/){
$pid = $1;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry didn't see the PhP tag (I'm new :( )