# Extract an int from a large string

Tags: java

I'm trying to get an `int` from a `String`. The `String` will always come as:

```
"mombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbohello=1?fdjaslkd;fdsjaflkdjfdklsa;fjdklsa;djsfklsa;dfjklds;afj=124214fdsamf=352"
```

The only constant in all of this, is that I will have a `"hello="` followed by a number. With just that, I can't figure out how to pull out the number after the `"hello="`. This is what I have tried so far with no luck.

EDIT: The number will always be followed by a "?"

```
String[] tokens = s.split("hello=");
for (String t : tokens)
    System.out.println(t);
```

I can't figure out how to isolate it from both sides of the `int`.

Comment: How big is your string roughly, and how important is performance?  I ask since unless your string is very very large and performance is very critical, then a regular expression could handle this quite easily.

Comment: It's about that size. Won't be any bigger.

Comment: Use regex instead. Very similar to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127898/use-regex-to-extract-integer-from-url-in-a-string-with-php

Comment: Then use the regular expression solution posted as an answer..  this is essentially what regular expressions are for.

Comment: @LeeMeador Yes it does, right after the mumbojumbo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("hello=(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher (s);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

This sets up a search for anywhere in `s` that contains hello= followed by one or more digits (`\\d+` means one or more digits).  The loop looks for each occurrence of this pattern, and then whenever it finds a match, `m.group(1)` extracts the digits (since those are grouped in the pattern).

Comment: I added an explanation.  Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Yes it is. Note that your answer now helps not just OP but future readers as well.

Comment: @EGHDK yes it will.  (Or actually the string "27".  If you want the actual integer, use [Integer.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) ).

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for this:

```
    String str = "mombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbohello=1fdjaslkd;fdsjaflkdjfdklsa;fjdklsa;djsfklsa;dfjklds;afj=124214fdsamf=352";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("hello=(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // prints 1
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String r = null;
int col = s.indexOf("hello="); // find the starting column of the marker string
if (col >= 0) {
    String s2 = s.substring(col + 6); // get digits and the rest (add length of marker)
    col = 0;
    // now find the end of the digits (assume no plus or comma or dot chars)
    while (col < s2.length() && Character.isDigit(s2.charAt(col))) {
        col++;
    }
    if (col > 0) {
        r = s2.substring(0, col); // get the digits off the front
    }
}
```

r will be the string you want or it will be null if no number was found.

Comment: +1 since this is most likely faster than a regex, however a regex is likely more straightforward and easier to modify if the situation changes (well, assuming you know your regular expressions).

Comment: @increment1 True you are. Since its simple ... a) find the start with indexOf, b) find where the sequence of digits end and c) get the string, I like this one. In real life, I would find the two column numbers first and do one `substring` call to avoid creating temporary strings. It's an old habit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another non-regex performance approach. Wrapped in a method for your convenience

Helper method

```
 public static Integer getIntegerForKey(String key, String s)
 { 
    int startIndex = s.indexOf(key);

    if (startIndex == -1)
        return null;

    startIndex += key.length();

    int endIndex = startIndex;

    int len = s.length(); 

    while(endIndex < len && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(endIndex))) {
        ++endIndex;
    }

    if (endIndex > startIndex)
        return new Integer(s.substring(startIndex, endIndex));

    return null;
 }
```

Usage

```
Integer result = getIntegerForKey("hello=", yourInputString);

if (result != null)
    System.out.println(result);
else
    System.out.println("Key-integer pair not found.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another non regex solution:

```
String str = "mombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbomombojumbohello=142?fdjaslkd;fdsjaflkdjfdklsa;fjdklsa;djsfklsa;dfjklds;afj=124214fdsamf=352";
char arr[] = str.substring(str.indexOf("hello=")+6).toCharArray();
String buff ="";
int i=0;
while(Character.isDigit(arr[i])){
    buff += arr[i++];
}
int result = Integer.parseInt(buff);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I just realized this is basically the same as the one from Lee Meador